# How to set breakpoint when I use vscode Code Runner extension to execute typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-code-runner

Here is my source code:
https://github.com/kody-liou/code-runner-set-breakpoint

I use the extension "Code Runner" to execute my typescript file.
I set a breakpoint then I press the "Run Code". The breakpoint was not working. I expect the breakpoint should be hit.

[image]

Here is my .vscode/settings.json

```json
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "code-runner.executorMap": {
    "typescript": "node_modules/.bin/ts-node-dev --inspect --"
  },
}
```